# Putting MYSQL table info into html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a guestbook, and I have a problem, that when I want my info from my mysql table to be placed into a table it only creates an empty table.

Code's here:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="117">Vardas</td>
<td width="14">:</td>
<td width="357"><? echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Komentaras</td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['comment']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"> Laikas </td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><? echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php }
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Are shortcodes supported? You're '{' of the while isn't closed. Is $tbl_name ok? Try var_dump($row) in youre while. Is there any output?

Comment: Oh, I didn't copy the code to the end. The while is closed. And it sends me an error and says null with the var_dump($row).

Comment: Not `var_dump($row)`, it is `var_dump($rows)`

Comment: I'm sorry for this little misstake. Try to do mysql_error(); Andrew. Do you get a error?

Comment: Does the query returns something when you run it in command line?

Comment: oh god such a stupid mistake... Yeah it gives me the array now. Then I guess there is a problem with my code inside the tables, right?

Comment: If short tags aren't ON, `<? echo $rows['id']; ?>` will fail. Either turn them on, or change to `<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>` and do the same for the others. @Andrew

Comment: @Fred-ii- The short tags was the problem! Thankyou very much everyone ^^

Comment: @Andrew Slightly unrelated, but important to say: mysql is deprecrated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: @StephanVierkant Yeah, thank You, but I'm not putting it online, just for my own education right now, but thanks ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If short tags aren't ON, `<? echo $rows['id']; ?>` will fail.

Either turn them on, or change to `<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>` and do the same for the others.

---

**Footnotes**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like;

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

to

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
```

You need to use associative array. Also this library is deprecated. Use [Mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: Try `var_dump($rows)` in while loop and tell me the result

Comment: The default `$result_type` is `MYSQL_BOTH` and it uses both `MYSQL_ASSOC` and `MYSQL_NUM` .. so , it is not the issue .
There is something wrong in the query itself or something